# Operator Filter not iterate by element sent from API

Tags: angular, operators, angular7

I am trying to work with operator filter of Angular 7. I have an api made in Express. Is an example simple. This API return an array of Object. Something like this:

```
[
  {name: 'Admin'}, 
  {name: 'Invitado'}, 
  {name: 'Ejecutivo'}
]
```

The API code is next:

```
function listRole(req, res) {
    var params = req.params;

    var page = 1;
    var cant = 10;

    if ( params.page ){
        page = parseInt(params.page);
    }

    if ( params.cant ){
        cant = parseInt(params.cant);
    }
    RoleModel.find().paginate(page, cant, (err, roles, total) => {
        if ( err ) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: err
            });
        }
        return res.status(200).send(
            roles
        );
    })

}
```

In the app of Angular 7, I have a service that return a list of Roles that matching with a params.

My service:

```
  getRoles(role: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.url).pipe(
      filter( (e: any) => {
        console.log(e) // this return an array
        return e.name === role;
      })
    );
  }
```

When I subscribe to this service, the data is null:

```
    this.userService.getRoles('Admin').subscribe( data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

My question is:
**Why the value e in operator filter return an array?**
**I think I should iterate over an array**

Any help is grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after searching several blogs.

**FlatMap operator transform the items emitted by an Observable into Observables, then flatten the emissions from those into a single Observable**

So, the first thing is to apply this operator so that it transforms the response into an Observable that emits elements and can go through each one. The solution is this:

```
  getRoles(role: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.url).pipe(
      flatMap( (data) => data ),
      filter( (e: any) => {
        return e.name === role;
      })
    );
  }
```

This solution is correct but has a detail. I can not iterate by the array of elements because flatMap return an Observable. That is, when I subscribe me to this service I not iterate by an array, in a template I can not use *ngFor.

This detail I solved it:

```
  getRoles(role: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.url).pipe(
      flatMap( (data) => data ),
      filter( (e: any) => {
        return e.name === role;
      }),
      toArray()
    );
  }
```